# Need to retrieve the Published data

Tags: 5.3

I am working with a legacy R5.3 GA based environment and I have a requirement to retrieve all the components which are published to a specific target and also filtered based on a schema.

I have written a custom code using TOM API (optimized it as per best of my knowledge) to do this task, however, the real problem is that there are millions of components and out which more then 50 K components are the result of the filtered query. Since It is older configuration hardware the result is taking more than 6 hours. (And this too sometime gives different result).
Is there any other possible faster and consistent way to retrieve this. Specifically, I am looking for a SQL query on Tridion Database which can give this result.

Comment: That's not a requirement... that's a proposed solution. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Apologies Dom if my question was not clear. I just wanted to share the context. I am just looking from experts if there is any other geek way to implement the requirement which could be more faster. If not, is it possible to have a SQL query which can be run directly on the Tridion DB to get the result (it may be slower but faster than API and will be consistent I guess)

Comment: Is this a one-off query to generate a one-time report, or do you need to do this over and over?

Comment: @Nick: One time query :)

Comment: You're on an older setup but with *today's* technology. So it's not just "[How would you do it without Tridion](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-would-you-do-it-without-tridion.html)?" but also *how would you do this today* (cloud instances, database tools, scripts, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at the *published* data instead of getting it from the CM.

Drop something like this on a .jsp or .aspx or whatever it is you use in your staging environment:

```java
ItemTypeCriteria componentCriteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(16);
Query q = new Query(CriteriaFactory.And(new Criteria[] { componentCriteria }));
SortParameter sortParameter = new SortParameter(SortParameter.ITEMS_TITLE, SortParameter.ASCENDING);
q.addSorting(sortParameter);
String[] componentResults = q.executeQuery();
```

And there you go, a list of published components at your fingertips.

PS - This code was written for 2011, it will *likely* not work in 5.3 (I think you only have `SearchFilter` as the query mechanism), but the principles are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Nuno gave the "fry" (in delivery) answer so here are the other two.

### Content Manager

The R5.3 User Manual describes Advanced Search's **Publish status** as

> The Publish status option searches for published or not published
>   items, selected using a drop down menu. Using the publish state search
>   feature will return only Components, Component Templates, and Pages.

The Business Connector was the precursor to the Core Service. Bart Koopman even describes the Core Service with it's Marketing/Business name: "Business Connector 2.0" in his [post on integrations](https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/tackleintegrations.aspx).

### Render / Publish

A quick and simple hack at finding information is using the TOM API as you have, but in template code.

I wouldn't suggest this for regular reporting, but you could get item XML which includes `<isPublished>` node. I have simple code examples for [XSLT](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/01/inspect-component-details-with-xslt.html) (per-item) and [C#](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/04/inspect-component-xml-with-c.html).

Both approaches deal with baking (in the Content Manager versus during Render/Publish). So just check the "oven." :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alvin.We have to omit the Advanced search option due to two reason: 1) It can not search on the basis of published to a specific target 2) The varity index are not reliable and in some cases can give you inconsistent results - Known issues with VF

Comment: Sure, in R5.3 you couldn't search on items published to a specific target. Though if not against a Live site, you *could* unpublish everywhere else first. Otherwise start by having everything that's published, published everywhere and then removing unwanted items. What's the known issue with Verity? I recall occasional issues with the search index getting out of sync (mostly when scripting new content), but there was/is a re-index script/tool.

Comment: Yes Alvin, what you said makes sense, but this approach will not be acceptable by the client considering the millions of components are there. Verity usually gives inconsistent result while there are search index are out of sync and re-indexing them is a time consuming task which will also not guarantee of 100% resolution